# GroupNorm implementation, how to get the exactly same result from Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have searched the implementation of PyTorch nn.GroupNorm.

```
N,C,H,W = x.size()
G = groups
assert C % G == 0

x = x.view(N,G,-1)
mean = torch.mean(x, -1, keepdim=True)
var = torch.var(x, -1, keepdim=True, unbiased=True)

x = (x-mean) / (var+eps).sqrt()
x = x.view(N,C,H,W)
```

And I compared the result of it with

```
torch.nn.GroupNorm(groups, channels, eps=eps, affine=False)
```

But the result isn't exactly the same.
My test input is

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
inp  = torch.arange(0, channels * 64 * 64).reshape(1, channels, 64, 64)
inp = inp / inp.max()
```

Could anyone tell me how to get the exactly same result to nn.GroupNorm

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are using the unbiased standard deviation estimator while `torch.groupnorm` is not: [ref](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GroupNorm.html#torch.nn.GroupNorm:%7E:text=equivalent%20to%20torch.var(input%2C%20unbiased%3DFalse)).

Here is a minimal working example:

```
>>> input = torch.randn(3, 6, 2, 2)
>>> N,C,H,W = input.shape
```

We first measure the group norm output with the builtin module:

```
>>> num_groups = 3
>>> eps = 1e-05
>>> m = nn.GroupNorm(num_groups=num_groups, num_channels=C, eps=eps)
>>> ref = m(input)
```

Then get the result manually:

```
>>> dims = list(range(-1,-4,-1)) # measure over last 3 dimensions
>>> var = input.var(dim=dims, keepdim=True, unbiased=False)
>>> avg = input.mean(dim=dims, keepdim=True)
>>> out = (input-avg)/torch.sqrt(var+eps)
```

Compare the two with:

```
>>> out.isclose(ref).all().item()
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I got for the output from your example is False

Comment: I'm sure the problem is caused by biased variance, and I may need float64 for the mean calculation to reduce the precision lost. Thank you again